# Wrapper Class Should be made static?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, security

I am planning on creating a wrapper class in c# which will call cryptographic functions provided by .Net Framework, just to make sure I am clear, I am not writing any cryptographic algorithm, just writing a wrapper to facilitate requests coming from other modules of Applications.

I have seen a lot of examples in which the wrapper class is made static, one of the reasons I could understand is that static class are sealed so they can not be inherited, and I think it would make sense to but I read somewhere that 
`Static classes are loaded automatically by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program or namespace containing the class is loaded.`

Is that going to be a problem since the class is loaded automatically way before it is used, security wise, should I make my wrapper class static?

Comment: You can seal ordinary classes as well, using the `sealed` keyword, so that's not a real reason to make your classes `static`.

Comment: [Regarding lifetime:](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) *"the type information for a static class is loaded by the .NET Framework common language runtime (CLR) when the program that references the class is loaded. The program cannot specify exactly when the class is loaded. However, it is guaranteed to be loaded and to have its fields initialized and its static constructor called before the class is referenced for the first time in your program..."*

Comment: *"... A static constructor is only called one time, and a static class remains in memory for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program resides."*

Comment: I wonder what's the memory footprint of a static class with JUST methods (no properties). I would assume it to be miniscule...?

Comment: If it is a static class with no state (i.e. with methods and no properties, and only local variables) then there's no security issue. However I would probably implement as instanced anyway, so I could code to an interface.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, so idea is to NOT go with static then?

Comment: One reason for Static is to restrict object creation and to avoid allocating memory for stateless objects. Sealed classes cannot be extended. Each with different goals.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that we are missing the essential background to this question, to give you specific advice on the question.  So, starting by answering your question, the answer is:

**Probably Not**

From a design perspective, there is only one good reason for making a class static:

**The class is just a collection of functions and has no state data. All of the data required by these functions is passed in as a parameter for each call.**

The advantage of using a static class when the above is true is that each method is very testable using test objects as parameters. Your main management challenge is ensuring that the intent for this class is clear and maintained over time - avoiding the common traps of static data being added (instead of creating a singleton class) or non related functions being added which dilue the intent and make the codebase less readable and maintainable.

*If your aim is to simplify the interface to the underlying encryption object calls, a stateless static class could work, but as you would be making your caller still do all of the hard work, and learn a non standard object as well - i don't think this approach is likely to be beneficial.*

Other options include:

- **Inheritance** - Just implement your class, using the encryption libraries object as your base class. Your class IS A type of base class.
- **Private property** - Implement your class, but within your class you maintain a private reference to the encryption libraries object. Your class HAS A type of base class.
- **Singleton** - If one of your requirements is that there should only be a single instance of your object at any one point in time, then you probably **should** implement your object as a singleton, using either inheritance or a private property to maintain a reference

Finally, is the business case for creating the wrapper class strong enough?  You will be creating extra overhead for the future in maintaining your code. It will make using your class non standard for developers that join the project. What are the benefits from doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Static classes are not immediately loaded into memory. They are loaded when requested.

Play the example below and see when the constructor message will appear on the screen.

Assuming this class was the third encryption mechanism

```cs
class EncryptionEngine
{
    public EncryptionEngine()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("ThirdParty EncryptionEngine is load now");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public string Encode(string text)
    {
        return text + " encoded by ThirdParty EncryptionEngine";
    }

    public string Decode(string text)
    {
        return text + " decoded by ThirdParty EncryptionEngine";
    }
}
```

This class plays the role of a static facade. This class is stateless and can be used by many system locations, it makes sense to use it as static to reduce the instantiation cost.

```cs
static class Wrapper
{
    static EncryptionEngine _encryptionEngine = new EncryptionEngine();

    static Wrapper()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Wrapper is loaded now");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    public static string Encode(string text)
    {
        return _encryptionEngine.Encode(text);
    }

    public static string Decode(string text)
    {
        return _encryptionEngine.Decode(text);
    }
}
```

Note the time when red and yellow messages appear on the screen and how often they appear. Even after repeating several times within the loop.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose an option:");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Encode");
            Console.WriteLine("2. Decode");

            var op = Console.ReadKey().Key;

            switch (op)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.D1:
                case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("text: ");
                    var text1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(Wrapper.Encode(text1));;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.D2:
                case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("text: ");
                    var text2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(Wrapper.Decode(text2));;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();

        } while (true);
    }
}
```

The messages do not appear immediately after running the program and do not appear more than once.

I hope it be useful!

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want a static class to load immediately, try using the `Lazy<T>` class or manually implementing the **Singleton** design pattern.

`Lazy<T>`:

```cs
public class Wrapper
{
    public string Encode()
    {
        //do something
    }

    public string Decode()
    {
        //do something
    }
}

public class YourController
{
    public Lazy<Wrapper> Wrapper { get; set; }

    public YourController()
    {
        Wrapper = new Lazy<Wrapper>();
    }

    public void Encode()
    {
        Wrapper.Value.Encode();
    }
}
```

You can read more about the `Lazy` class here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=netframework-4.8

**Singleton**:

```cs
public class Wrapper
{
    public string Encode()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string Decode()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class YourController
{
    static Wrapper _singleton;

    public static Wrapper Wrapper
    {
        get
        {
            if (_singleton == null)
                return _singleton = new Wrapper();

            return _singleton;
        }
    }

    public void Encode()
    {
        Wrapper.Encode();
    }
}
```

Learn more about Singleton here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-design-pattern/

Comment: Not sure I follow, static classes are loaded by .Net CLR.

Comment: Excuse. I did not understand. What is making you worried?

Comment: your first statement If you don't want a static class to load immediately, one can not control when static class will be loaded.

Comment: Got it. I will add a new answer to give you a code example about when the static class is instantiated.

Comment: Please do not suggest an [anti-pattern like Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755539/why-is-singleton-considered-an-anti-pattern) to someone who has not even expressed any need for it.